# Оптимизация разбиения строки

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть некий кусок кода, подгружающий строки из файла в коллекцию с уникальными значениями

```
var WORDS = new Set()

let file = fs.readFileSync('file.txt') // 1 500 000+ строк
// Прошло ~10 мс
let text = iconv.decode(file, 'windows-1251')
// Прошло ~100 мс
let list = text.split('\n')
// Прошло ~500 мс

let i = 0
while (list[i] != null) {
    // Быстрее, чем "WORDS = new Set(list)"
    WORDS.add(list[i++])
}

// Прошло ~1100 мс
```

Самые толстые части кода — разбиение по ячейкам и перебор. Возможно ли это оптимизировать?

**UPD:**
Делается всё ради того, что бы быстро искать значение в коллекции

```
WORDS.has('string') // true или false
```

Так что, если есть другие способы хранения и поиска уникальных значений, я за

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну если без шуток, то у Вас происходит два обращения к одному и тому же элементу массива. Вот так будет точно быстрее -

```
let length = list.length;

for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
    Worlds.add(list[i]);
}
```

А по поводу просто проверки на существование, тут сложно сказать без замеров.
`Set` работает со всеми типами, что должно сделать его работу теоретически медленнее чем обычный объект, который является базовым типом для всего в `js` и использует в качестве ключа строку. Я о -

```
let hash = {};

hash[list[i]] = true;

console.log(hash['string']);
```

добавление в `Set` -

```js
const CharFactory = {
  count: 0,
  getChar(){
    return 'some text' + this.count++;
  },
  reset(){
    this.count = 0;
  }
};

const ITERATION = 1000000;

const set = new Set();

console.time('add in Set');
for(let i = 0; i < ITERATION; i++){
  set.add(CharFactory.getChar());
}
console.timeEnd('add in Set');
```

добавление в `Object` -

```js
const CharFactory = {
  count: 0,
  getChar(){
    return 'some text' + this.count++;
  },
  reset(){
    this.count = 0;
  }
};

const ITERATION = 1000000;

const hash = {};

console.time('add in Object');
for(let i = 0; i < ITERATION; i++){
  hash[CharFactory.getChar()] = true;
}
console.timeEnd('add in Object');
```

проверка в `Set` -

```js
const CharFactory = {
  count: 0,
  getChar(){
    return 'some text' + this.count++;
  },
  reset(){
    this.count = 0;
  }
};

const ITERATION = 1000000;

const set = new Set();

for(let i = 0; i < ITERATION; i++){
  set.add(CharFactory.getChar());
}

CharFactory.reset();

console.time('has in Set');
for(let i = 0; i < ITERATION; i++){
  let isCharExistValid = set.has(CharFactory.getChar());
}
console.timeEnd('has in Set');
```

проверка в `Object` -

```js
const CharFactory = {
  count: 0,
  getChar(){
    return 'some text' + this.count++;
  },
  reset(){
    this.count = 0;
  }
};

const ITERATION = 1000000;

const hash = {};

for(let i = 0; i < ITERATION; i++){
  hash[CharFactory.getChar()] = true;
}

CharFactory.reset();

console.time('has in Object');
for(let i = 0; i < ITERATION; i++){
  let isCharExistValid = hash[CharFactory.getChar()];
}
console.timeEnd('has in Object');
```

Хоть это и нужно тестировать именно в той ноде в которой вы работает, я все же не удержался и написал тесты для браузера.

Comment: Действительно, не подумал. Код действительно ускорился, но к сожалению только на 50 мс. Плюс, я всегда думал что length это геттер и при его вызове будет происходить лишний подсчет количества ячеек, что будет занимать время. Во всяком случае, на фронтенде так было

Comment: По поводу объектов — сперва код так и был написан, но как не парадоксально, Set работает в полтора раза быстрее, поэтому и перешёл на него

Comment: По поводу length Вы правы и мало того что это геттер, который должен пересчитываться при изменении массива, а не при обращении, но я так уже привык.

Comment: Я протестировал ваши примеры в ноде — действительно, быстрее работают объекты. Но с моим кодом почему-то иные обстоятельства
http://rextester.com/GKVS16394

Comment: Ну, плюс у вас нет присвоений в примере на создание объекта — ключи не создаются а просто перебираются пустые ячейки, соответственно это быстрее

Comment: А по поводу самой разрезки строки, то когда-то `indexOf` резал быстрее всех.

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz точно! Исправил.

Comment: По поводу indexOf — имеется виду не разбивать строку, а осуществлять поиск уже в тексте, или я не так понял?

Comment: Не, я о разбиении. Я когда-то делал и проверял, получалось быстрее, но это на первой ноде. Типа indexOf принимает же два параметра, второй индекс с которого нужно начинать поиск. И вот получается, делаем поиск первого переноса строки, запоминаем и при втором проходе этот индекс используем как начало для следующего поиска. И так по шагам пройти весь файл.

Comment: идея хорошая, но всё так скорость уменьшилась :/
Помимо indexOf приходится использовать два substr в каждой итерации

Comment: Хотя здесь быстрее http://rextester.com/WFXV26395 Очень странно

Comment: Зачем два, один! Начинаете с startIndex = 0 endIndex = fileData.indexOf('\n', startIndex) далее вырезаете кусок и делаете startIndex = endIndex. И так шаг за шагом. И я не пользуюсь сервисами для тестов, я сам их пишу. Так я уверен, что они выполняются в нужном мне окружении, а не банально компилируются в другой-неподходящий мне es* и что версия v8 именно та.

Comment: http://rextester.com/GKX57522

Answer (score 0):

Для производительности стоит делать только один проход по строке.

```js
let WORDS = {};

let file = fs.readFileSync('file.txt') // 1 500 000+ строк

let text = iconv.decode(file, 'windows-1251');

let len = text.length;
let offset = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
  if ((text[i] == '\n' || text[i] == '\r') && offset != i) {
    WORDS[text.substring(offset, i)] = true;
    offset = i + 1;
  }
}
if (offset != len - 1) {
  WORDS[text.substring(offset, len)] = true;
}
```

Comment: Тоже думал об этом и пробовал, но в итоге вышло в два раза медленней. Видимо нативный split() работает быстрее, чем проверка на "\n". И вы так же можете присоединиться к обсуждению о скорости объектов и Set-коллекций в комментариях предыдущего ответа (http://rextester.com/GKVS16394)